# Adding different class for every six list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a different class for every six list item using jQuery.

I've tried looking at `.append()` and `.after()` but I'm unsure of the logic in using these.

How would I achieve the following structure via JQuery:

```
<ul>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
</ul>
```

I also want to move that group of six items with same class to the top of the list upon clicking a button.

Script:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('ul li.blue').append($('ul li:nth-child(2)'));
});
```

Comment: where do these classes get defined? It's not 100% clear what your final goals are

Comment: This looks like a job for .prepend()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice) method as follows:

```
var colors = ["white", "blue", "red"];
var $listItems = $("li");
$.each(colors, function(i, color) {
  $listItems.slice(i * 6, ++i * 6).addClass(color);
  $("body").append($("<button/>", {
    text: color,
    css: {
      "background-color": color
    }
  }))
});
```

```js
var colors = ["white", "blue", "red"];
var $listItems = $("li");
$.each(colors, function(i, color) {
  $listItems.slice(i * 6, ++i * 6).addClass(color);
  $("body").append($("<button/>", {
    text: color,
    css: {
      "background-color": color
    }
  }))
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('ul li.' + $(this).text()).prependTo('ul');

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.white {
  background: #fff;
}
.blue {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>red</li>
</ul>
```

---

### UPDATE

According to your comment, you can extract colors from [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) attributes using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) method like:

```
var colors = $("div").map(function(){
  return $(this).data("color");
});
```

---

You can use the jQuery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method to iterate over the array of colors we extracted.

In each iteration, we create a new `<li>` with the text and class equal to the color being iterated.

Then we create an HTMLString corresponding to `n` number of such elements by passing the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) of the sample `<li>` we created to array [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method like:

```
new Array(7).join($li.get(0).outerHTML);
```

We then [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) this `HTMLString` to the `<ul>`, also we create a button that [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend)'s a group of similar `<li>` to the `<ul>` in order to bring them on top of the list.

---

```js
var colors = $("div").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("color");
});
var $ul = $("ul"),
  $body = $("body");
$.each(colors, function(i, color) {
  var $li = $("<li/>", {
    text: color,
    class: color
  });
  $ul.append(new Array(7).join($li.get(0).outerHTML));
  $body.append($("<button/>", {
    text: color,
    css: {
      "background-color": color
    },
    on: {
      click: function() {
        $('ul li.' + $(this).text()).prependTo('ul');
      }
    }
  }));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.white {
  background: #fff;
}
.blue {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="white"></div>
<div data-color="blue"></div>
<div data-color="red"></div>
<ul>
</ul>
```

---

*Side notes:* If you want to have different text for the buttons, you can save the data as a `data-*` attribute and use it to find the corresponding group.

Also, I've added the CSS classes for the sake of demo, You should apply the css while creating `<li>` since it is not practical to have predefined CSS classes while doing this dynamically.

Comment: Amazing, thanks all! I like this solution as I need to get the colours from data-attributes so then I need to put them in an array similar to this. Could you give me a pointer in how I would get the colours from divs like <div data-colour="blue"> for example? Thanks!

Comment: I know that you've dynamically created the button based on colours in the array but I have these buttons (swatches) already in place (coming from another data source). Could you show me how I could use your code but without the button being generated so I still use the click functionality? Thanks!

Comment: @casiokid how does your button relate to a particular group..? An id/class/data attribute, or text..? The first snippet contains a demo based on button text...

Comment: They are related by the data attribute data-color="", so your map function gets all the colours from these buttons/divs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ztpwk0tn/4/)**

You want to `.prepend()` your `li`'s.

HTML

```
<button id="white">Move White</button><button id="blue">Move Blue</button><button id="red">Move Red</button>
<ul>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="white">white</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    var color = $(this).prop('id');
    var $lis = $('li.' + color);
    $lis.remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < $lis.length; i++) {
        $('ul').prepend('<li class="' + color + '">' + color + '</li>');
    }        
});
```

CSS

```
li {
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

.white {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.blue {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.red {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

#### Update

I updated to work with a variable number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response and that's almost what I'm looking for!

Sorry I didn't give enough info. Rather than one button, I have 3 colour buttons and when I click the colour button, the list items with that class need to move to the top of the list.

i.e. when I click 'blue', blue moves to the top of list (from a middle position).

Thanks!

Comment: That's great, thanks so much! As the other solution above, I need to get these colours dynamically from data attributes (so <div data-colour="blue">). Do you know what the best way would be to integrate this with your solution? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, but I will need more info. Are you generating the `li` tags dynamically with the colors from like a parent div? Does one div have all the colors?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/vkgrozj8/3/

```
$('input').click( function(e) {
    var c = $(e.target).val();
    $('ul').find('.'+c).each( function( index, element ) {
        console.log(element);
        $('ul').prepend(element);
    });
});
```